# Howto place the start button in the middle of the clip

Tags: video.js

I found the designer page on http://www.videojs.com/ there you can change the position of the start button to be in the middle of your clips.

But I am not able to place or use this stylesheets on the video.js player. Could some one explain how to use it in the player. E. G. to extend the existing css with an extra file? or how to change the existing css to place the button not on the left top but in the middle?

Thanks. Katasun

Answer (score 19):

You can add '**vjs-big-play-centered**' to video class.

```
 <video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="700" height="450" poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg"><source src="" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using version 4.1.0:

In video-js.css, in `.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button` (line 484+) replace:

```
top: 2em;
left: 2em;
margin: 0;
```

with:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -6em;
margin-top: -4em;
```

-6em and -4em because the width is 12em and height is 8em

Just had the same problem and had to fix it this way :) Works on the latest chrome, firefox, safari and opera, didn't test on IE, i'm on OSX

Comment: This was helpful and is working for me, but I have no apple devices to test it on apple. Thanks

Comment: Yes I will accept your answer, but I don't know how to do this? Maybe you have a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended a version of videojs where you can place the play button anywhere. This also means being able to touch the thumbnail anyway on IOS devices (doesn't have to be the center) and it will run the video. http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html