# VideoJS centered play button

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I thought I'd share a piece of code that might come in handy to someone. This is a function that center's the play button inside the video-js player, it works for me. You just need to call it on the pause event and when the player is initialized and not being autoplayed.

Enjoy!

```
function CenterPlayBT() {
   var playBT = $(".vjs-big-play-button");
   playBT.css({
      left:( (playBT.parent().outerWidth()-playBT.outerWidth())/2 )+"px",
      top:( (playBT.parent().outerHeight()-playBT.outerHeight())/2 )+"px"
   });
}
```

Comment: As of [video.js version 4.3](http://blog.videojs.com/post/66138384272/video-js-version-4-3-0-released-w-shiny-new-api-docs) you can simply add the `vjs-big-play-centered` class to the video element. With earlier 4.x versions you  can use `.vjs-big-play-button { left: 50%; top: 50% }`

Comment: This isn't a question, really. You could rewrite it and ask how to center the button, then answer it. Or ask @misterben to answer.

Comment: internet bless you :P

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426487/howto-place-the-start-button-in-the-middle-of-the-clip

Comment: @misterben you have made my day ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 103):

You can try to play at videojs.com or as @misterben said above:

> Simply add the `vjs-big-play-centered` class to the video element.

```
<video id="my_video"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
    width="640" height="360"...></video>
```

Playground: https://codepen.io/heff/pen/EarCt

For SCSS version you may use

```
$center-big-play-button: true;
```

Comment: Indeed the link is dead due to videojs.com. You can play here: http://codepen.io/heff/pen/EarCt

Answer (score 1):

Create video-js-custom.css place after:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.9.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="link-to-custom-css/video-js-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add of video-js-custom.css:

```
.video-js .vjs-big-play-button {
    left: 40% !important;
    top: 40% !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

.video-js .vjs-play-control:before {
    top:20% !important;
    content: '\f101';
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: the box is positioned in the middle but the play icon not scaled down well

Answer (score 1):

**In all the devices (Mobiles and PC) you can center align play-button using below css style**

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button {
            left: 50% !important;
            top: 50% !important;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 80px!important;
            height: 80px!important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em!important;
            -moz-border-radius: 0.8em!important;
            border-radius: 1.9em!important;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version `"video.js": "^7.7.5"` following config works for me:
class `vjs-big-play-centered` centers the button on player.

Stylesheet

```
 <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- City -->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/themes@1/dist/city/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

HTML

```
<video
  id="my-video"
  class="video-js vjs-theme-city vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls
  playsinline
  preload="auto"
  width="640"
  height="480"
  data-setup="{}"
>
  <source src="{{this.url}}" type="application/x-mpegURL"/>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
    web browser that
    <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
    >supports HTML5 video</a
    >
  </p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Javascript version (based on @Adrian's answer):

```
<video id="my_video"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
    width="640" height="360"...></video>
```

- React version:

```
import { Player, BigPlayButton } from 'video-react'
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Player className="video-video" >
      <source src={"/video.mp4"} />
      <BigPlayButton position={"center"} />
    </Player>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

http://designer.videojs.com - at the bottom of the less just add:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button {
  margin-left: -@big-play-width/2;
  margin-top: -@big-play-height/2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom CSS to your code

```
.vjs-big-play-button {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    width: 70px !important;
    height: 70px !important;
}
```

Adjust width and height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use "limelight player" that uses video.js to deliver HTML5 solution but I have problem to center play button icon in iOS devices. Reported issue and support could not come with solution. They did confirm issue.  I thought of sharing my solution that might help somebody. Solution was simple: decrease font size! Besides the "font-size" there is inherited "line-height" property that might need adjustment too. These two properties increase parent container and misalignment happens if parent container is not set to be relative or video player container is set to be responsive (width:100% ; height:100%)

So CSS solution that helped me was:

```
.video-js .vjs-limelight-big-play{ 
      font-size:100px!important /*or less */
}
```

Or even better switch from PX to EM which will help in mobile devices (iOS experienced issue with centering of a play button too)

```
.video-js .vjs-limelight-big-play{ 
      font-size:10em!important /*or less depending on your design*/
}
```